# Passing data to another component does not working

Tags: reactjs

first of all I am pretty new to react and developing a react app. In my app, I am fetching data from an api inside **componentDidmount()**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
       employeeData:[]
    }
}
  componentDidMount(){
      axios.get("http://localhost:8080/hris/api/employee/123456/personal?authToken=ldkasjfdsoue",  
      )
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then((data) => {  

       this.setState({ employeeData: data },()=> 
     //console.log("dfdf"+JSON.stringify(this.state.employeeData['employeeID']))) 
**// i am getting the data here**
       })
      .catch(err=> console.log("whyerror"+err)) 

    }
```

I stored this data into state. But when I want to send data into another component, **error occurs**.

```
      {console.log("isdata"+JSON.stringify(this.state.employeeData))}
   {/* {<Table data={this.state.employeeData}/> } */}
```

here I am getting all data, but when I am doing this

```
   {console.log("isdata"+JSON.stringify(this.state.employeeData))}
   {<Table data={this.state.employeeData}/> }
```

**Table.js**

```
constructor(props){  

      super(props);
      console.log('thisprops'+JSON.stringify(props))  //giving null value


    }
```

This shows that the **Table** component received null props. 
 Now how can I pass data to Table component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Table data={this.state.employeeData}/>`
No need to wrap with brackets, this is JSX and not javascript

better yet do this
`<Table data={JSON.stringify(this.state.employeeData)}/>` to avoid standalone code

Comment: my file extension is file.js type

Comment: @ShakirUzZaman have you tried this, I don't think you have to change your file extension though, it should work regardless.

Comment: i think i dont have to change file extension @NoriodeRaphael

Comment: actually I found the exact problem . Thanks all !

Answer (score 1):

What error occurs? Is employeeData an array? If so then you can make the initial employeeData as an empty array like;

**ParentComponent.jsx**

```js
export class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      employeeData: []
    }
  }

 componentDidMount(){
      axios.get("http://localhost:8080/hris/api/employee/123456/personal?authToken=ldkasjfdsoue",  
      )
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then((data) => {this.setState({ employeeData: JSON.stringify(data)})
      .catch(err=> console.log("whyerror"+err)) 
    }

  render(){
    return (
       <Table data={this.state.employeeData}/>
    )
  }
}
```

**Table.jsx**

```js
export class Table extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
     console.log(this.props.data) // it should be here
  }

  render(){
    return (
       {  
         this.props.data && this.props.data.map((employee) => {
            ...
         })
       }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try it again and see what console logs at componentDidMount at Table component?

Comment: actually I found the solution! thanks ! componentDidmount() will make two render. So first one is with empty data without fetching data . and 2nd one is with fetching data . I just made a logic , if  this.employee.data is null or empty , the render will not load .